# Will 15 litre IKEA FÖRENKLA qualify as a personal item?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, tips-and-tricks, hand-luggage

I'm shopping for a new backpack.  I like the features and especially the price of ***IKEA FÖRENKLA***, and there are two versions:

- [903.135.63](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/90313563/) — 11cm×28cm×39cm, for a total of 12 litres (12012cm³) or 3 gallons
- [303.292.08](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/30329208/) — 11cm×28cm×48cm, for a total of 15 litres (14784cm³) or 4 gallons

As I am 190cm tall (6'3"), I'm thinking that perhaps the taller version would suit me better, however, according to https://www.united.com/CMS/en-US/travel/Pages/BaggageCarry-On.aspx:

> **Personal item**
>
> The maximum dimensions for your personal item, such as a shoulder bag, backpack, laptop bag or other small item, are 9 inches x 10 inches x 17 inches (22 cm x 25 cm x 43 cm).

If we multiply 22cm×25cm×43cm, we get 23650cm³, which is close to 24 litres.  However, the 15 litre IKEA backpack above may be a couple of inches longer in width and height (looks like even the smaller one is technically about an inch longer in width than what is allowed).

The questions:

- Will anyone care if I get and carry on the 15L backpack, or will it be an issue?
- Will it fit into the sizing apparatus?  (I recall that the last time I travelled by air, which was many months ago, they had those only for the rolling-wheel carry-on bags, not for the personal items.)
- Will I have to pack it in such a way as for it to fit into any sort of a sizing apparatus, for showing it off, or would that make no difference either way?

Comment: Does it squish? That usually will get you by.

Answer (score 11):

**Depends**, but you're probably OK. I always travel with a rollaboard and a largish backpack, and I've never had any questions from a legacy carrier, much less attempts to measure it.  Instead of measuring racks, I think the intuitive measure is "will it fit under your seat", and if it looks like it will, you're golden.

Now LCCs tend to be a lot more strict and may define personal items a lot more strictly or ban them outright, so I wouldn't try this on (say) Ryanair, but that's another story.

Comment: +1 for the "will it fit under the seat" check; plus I would add a note that even if it does fit, you may be required to gate-check the item if the flight is particularly full.

Comment: Re: low-cost carriers, Southwest doesn't care either (source: I fly Southwest).

Answer (score 6):

United supposedly cancelled my flight and/or reservation, so, I flew Delta and Southwest.  They didn't seem to care at all, and noone even bothered to weigh, count or measure anyone's carry-ons.

I did see the same measuring device at United as depicted on their web-site, which lets one measure both the personal item, as well as carry-on bag; however, I haven't seen anyone actually using it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me emphasize: noone cares about volumes. Gate agents might force you to put your luggage in the sizer which is a bit bigger than the published dimensions, for the personal item it's 9" x 11" x 18". Your bag won't fit so I would not risk it.

Comment: FYI: it's been a while since I've seen a gate agent doing anything like that; empirical evidence seems to suggest that noone cares about these dimensions, as long as the personal item is small enough